# How to pass value to std::optional in a structure?

Tags: c++, option-type

I am trying to use the std::optional as in the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <string>

struct Animal {
    std::string name;
};

struct Person {
    std::string name;
    std::optional<Animal> pet;
};

int main() {
    Person person;
    person.name = "John";
    
    if (person.pet) {
        std::cout << person.name << "'s pet's name is " <<
            person.pet->name << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << person.name << " is alone." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I want to know how can I pass value to the optional parameter pet which is structure.
I tried doing

```
person.pet = std::make_optional<Animal>("Bru");
```

and

```
person.pet = "Bru"
```

But both of these dont work. How should I pass the value to my parameter here?

Comment: It may help to define a constructor for both of these `struct`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
person.pet = "Bru"
```

Your pet field isn't a string, it's an `Animal`, so you need to pass an `Animal` instance to this. Try this instead:

```
person.pet = Animal { "Bru" };
```

Or simply:

```
person.pet = { "Bru" };
```

Comment: Here my animal structure had one field, i.e name. How do I pass parameter if my Animal had more than one paramter, say my Animal has paramter name and colour. Then how do i pass?

Comment: Using commas, for example `person.pet = { "Name", "red" };`. Though I strongly recommend adding constructors instead of using this implicit way of constructing objects.

Comment: can you tell me how can I use constructors here?

Comment: Define them and use them. For example in your `Animal` you can add `Animal(const char *name) : name(name) {}`. The calling code doesn't change, `{ "Bru" }` will call the real constructor if available.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to construct an `Animal` object with a `char array`, that can't be done like that.

One option would be construct it in place when you create the `std::optional` instance.

```
person.pet = std::make_optional(Animal{"Bru"});
```

Or, more cryptic:

```
person.pet = std::make_optional<Animal>({{"Bru"}});
```

But, as [@t.niese mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341691/how-to-pass-value-to-stdoptional-in-a-structure/64341835#comment113775968_64341835) one of `std::make_optional`'s good features is to not need the template parameter, so the second option is not as nice.

[@Blindy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64341787/6865932) is also good, I do prefer to use the `std::make_*` functions when available, but I guess in this case it shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: The idea behind the `make_*` functions is to remove the need to specify the template parameters. And why introduce a local variable, if you just could write `std::make_optional(Animal{"Bru"});`

Comment: @t.niese, yes, that's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Im unsure why you want to use optional here. However what your doing

```
person.pet = "Bru"
```

is setting person.pet to a string, when you have

```
 std::optional<Animal> pet;
```

Making it so you are actually setting pet to an animal struct.

so to get what you want you need to declare a new animal object like this.

```
int main() {
    Person person;
    person.name = "John";

    Animal _animal;
    _animal.name = "bru"; 
    person.pet = _animal;

    if (person.pet) {
        std::cout << person.name << "'s pet's name is " <<
            person.pet->name << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << person.name << " is alone." << std::endl;
    }

    
}
```