# Assigning a non optional variable to std::optional variable

Tags: c++, option-type

I have a class with an optional field declared of `void const *` (I'm also confused if to * outside the angle brackets or inside.

```
class Test {
protected:
    std::optional<void const> *_data;  // void const *_data
public:
    explict Test(void const *data = nullptr);
}
```

In the Test.cpp file.

```
Test(const void *data) {
    this->_data = data; // error
}
```

[image]

Comment: `_data` is a pointer to a `std::optional<void const>`. `std::optional` is useful for cases when you need to assign the null-concept to your object, but that object type has no natural null-concept. Normally pointer types have the natural null-concept of `nullptr`, so they usually don't need to be wrapped in a `std::optional`. The semantics for checking for a `nullptr` are equal to checking for a `std::nullopt`: `if (_data) { _data->do_thing(); }`. However, if `nullptr` isn't "null enough" for your application, then a `std::optional<void const *>` makes sense.

Comment: Please specify your exact, verbatim error.

Comment: `void const*` is also equivalent to `const void*`. `const` in a type specifier refers to the "thing" to the left of `const`, except in the special case where the "first" thing in your type should be `const`, and you can place `const` to either the left or right of it. I think this is just for readability - maybe backwards compatability. Someone else can speak on the historical reasons. I personally prefer `const void*` to `void const*`, but you can find both in the wild. It's just a style thing.

Comment: now that you made the clear with the comparison of `void const*` and `const void*`, I also prefer `const` first, because this is what i have been used to in other languages. Thanks.

Comment: Added error, so my understanding is, I don't need to use `optional` with pointers because they already come as a nullable object and its the responsibility of the caller of the function to check for the null for the returned value.

Comment: now adding to the mix based on `const` discussion, this declaration of a field in a class also throws me a little bit `constexpr static char const *const NAME = "Test";` two `const`s are confusing for me.

Comment: **its the responsibility of the caller of the function to check for the null for the returned value** correct - which your user would have to do with a `std::optional` anyway. Now, another option is to specify that it's "undefined behavior" or "illegal" for a user of your class to construct it with a `nullptr`. And that it's not a valid state for the object to exist with a `nullptr` sitting inside of it. That puts the responsibility on the "creator" of the object, and not the "user" (even though they're likely the same human). This all depends on whether it's valid for your _data to be nullptr

Comment: `constexpr static char const *const NAME = "Test";` is a `const` pointer (the value of the *pointer* shall not be changed) to a `const char` (the value of the `char`s in the array shall not be changed). The `constexpr` makes some of this redundant, since `constexpr` implies `const` anyway.

Comment: The whole `constexpr const const *** const char const ** = <string literal>;` discussion is a different question.

Comment: incorporating feedback, `constexpr static const char *NAME = "Test";` would you prefer to write it this way?

Comment: **see second comment below** I'd prefer to write it `static constexpr const char* name = "Test";`. The `static`/`constexpr` order is a style thing, and so is the case of the `name`, since `NAME` (all caps) implies preprocessor directive to me. But they way you've written it is totally comprehensible. It's a style thing. If you're writing in an existing code base, copy whatever style they use. otherwise, use my style, because my style is the best.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I'd actually prefer to write this is `static constexpr std::string_view name = "Test";` if we have the option of C++17, which I recommend if it's available with your compiler.

Comment: I have the control over the style, since its a new library, incorporated `string_view`, any link for this `constexpr const const *** const char const ** = <string literal>;`, I'm curious.

Comment: Your use case might be better served by `std::any`, which is a pretty feature-par-but-safer replacement for `void*`. Depending on whether you have a finite list of possible types, `std::variant` is generally a preferable option when applicable.

Comment: That const-salad was a joke. You can get wacky with that stuff, but it's usually code smell to have to go so deep on the const.

Comment: `std::make_optional(someValue)` - see also [How to pass value to std::optional in a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341691/how-to-pass-value-to-stdoptional-in-a-structure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, where `_data` is a non-const pointer to a `std::optional` (it doesn't matter that the `std::optional` holds a `const void` type), you're trying to assign a pointer to a `const` object (of unknown `void` type) to a non-const pointer.

This violates the contract of your class constructor, where you promise not to modify the object being pointed at (not just in the constructor, but ever). Consider this simplified example:

```
template <typename T>
Test {
protected:
    T* _data;

public:
    explict Test(const void * data = nullptr) {
        _data = data; // ERROR: can't assign a const-pointer to a non-const pointer
    }
}
```

Your issue has nothing to do with `std::optional`.

Consider that you might not even need to wrap your pointer in a `std::optional`, since pointers already have the natural nullable-concept of `nullptr`:

```
class Test {
protected:
    const void* _data;
public:
    explict Test(void const *data = nullptr) {
        _data = data;
    }

    void do_thing() const {
        if (_data) { // nullable semantics naturally work on pointers, no need for `std::optional`
        // UNLESS `nullptr` isn't "null enough" for your application
            // do (const-qualified) operation on _data.
        }
    }
}
```

### On the concept of `std::optional`, pointers, and nullable

> it's the responsibility of the caller of the function to check for the null for the returned value

correct - and your user would have to do with a `std::optional` anyway.

Another option is to specify that it's "undefined behavior" or "illegal" for a user of your class to construct it with a `nullptr`. And that it's not a valid state for the object to exist with a `nullptr`. That shifts the responsibility on the "creator" of the object, and not the "user" (even though they're likely the same human). This all depends on whether it's valid for your `_data` to be `nullptr`.

Decide what the valid states of your object are allowed to be, and whose responsibility it is to enforce that. If you design your interface correctly, you can eliminate a lot of `if` checks that would otherwise need to be scattered throughout all layers of the code.

Some of the responsibility lives with the object creator (user), some of the responsibility lives within the class (this could be shared with the user-creator for validity checks, or ignored), and some lies with the object user (application developer).